# There is some problem about expect in linux,and raspberry

Tags: linux, ssh, raspberry-pi, expect

There is some problem in my system, I write a script shell just like thie,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
spawn ssh -p$port $username@$ip

expect {
"*yes/no" { send "yes\r";exp_continue}
"*password:" { send "pass"}
}
#expect '$*' {send "sudo systemctl stop wind_dete\r"}
expect '$*' {send 'sudo pkill mysql'}
expect "$*" {send "sudo  mkdir test\r"}
interact
```

but anyway,this `expect '$*' {send 'sudo pkill mysql'}` can't execute,but `expect "$*" {send "sudo  mkdir test\r"}` execute success.
when I execute `expect xx.sh`,there show this

```
:~ $ sudo pkill mysql
:~ $ exit
```

this is executed successd, I can't get any idea about this, that's why lead this case, and how can I pkill mysql from one of my server.
I really need help, and I will  appreciate your idea and suggestion.

Comment: The main problem with `expect` is its overuse with `ssh`. Use public-key authentication if you want to log in without typing a password. If you are going to blindly type "yes" for whether to accept a host key, just use `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` to avoid the question.

Comment: `expect -d /the/script.exp` can show you detailed debug info.

Comment: Spend 10 minutes to set up Public Key Authentication and avoid a lifetime of pain.

Answer (score 2):

Expect is based on the Tcl language, so Tcl syntax must be used for strings. Single quotes `'` have no special meaning in Tcl and will treated literally, so `expect '$*'` will look for a pattern which starts and ends with a single quote, which is unlikely to match anything in practice.  Double quotes `"` can be used to enclose a string.  For more details see https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/Tcl.htm#M8 .

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion,  but I tried and it didn't work.

Comment: Quoting might not be the only thing wrong here, but it certainly needs to be corrected.  As @sexpect says, using the debugging option to expect is likely to show what exactly is happening.